# Change button background Activated MainWindow with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'am learning c# (Visual Studio 2019). In the MainWindow I have a frame with a page1.xaml. This page1 has several buttons. On Activated the MainWindow I would like to change the background of one of the buttons in the page1 in red color. How I can do this?
Thank you in advance for any answer
Sabine

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please provide some information about what you have tried so far. It will be easy to check. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the Name(say **button1**) to the button, in WPF button background need to be SolidColorBrush not directly Color,*so as page loads add this code in PageFunction after InitializeComponent();*

```
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);// convert color to brush            
        button1.Backgroud=brush;// apply the brush
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. But the button is not in the MainWindow. The Button is on the page SubMenueSammlung.xaml in a frame named "SubMenue".

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <!--Page SubMenueSammlung.xaml-->
    <Grid Background="#FFF2F2F2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="24">
        <Frame x:Name="SubMenue" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>            
    </Grid>

    <!--Content-->
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="Main" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

On Activated the MainWindow in the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public void FillFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SubMenue.Content = new SubMenueSammlung();
    }
```

The MainWindow opens, the Frame SubMenue gets the page "SubMenueSammlung.xaml". And now I don't know what to do next...
I want a button on the page "SubMenueSammlung" in the frame to have a red background.

I have a style for this Button:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="redButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF900000"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
```

Thanks Sabine

Please excuse my english, I am a german woman